# Java + Maven1.x : how to add sun's tools.jar?

Tags: java, maven-1

I must add tools.jar into my **maven1** build config but I can't find any help.

Here is the solution I've found using the helpfull sugestion of geo:

I have modified the maven.xml build in order to add the tools.jar in the classpath.
A pre-goal before java:compile does the stuff:

```
<preGoal name="java:compile">
    <ant:path id="tools">
        <ant:pathelement path="${tools.jar}"/>
    </ant:path>
    <maven:addPath id="maven.dependency.classpath" refid="tools"/>
</preGoal>
```

Below are result of my investiqgations and can be helpfull for someone trying to achieve the same unsing **maven 2.x**

> How do I include tools.jar in my
>   dependencies?
>
> The following code includes tools.jar
>   for JDKs on Windows, Linux and Solaris
>   (it is already included in the runtime
>   for Mac OS X and some free JDKs).
>
> ```
>   ...
>   <profiles>
>     <profile>
>       <id>default-tools.jar</id>
>       <activation>
>         <property>
>           <name>java.vendor</name>
>           <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
>         </property>
>       </activation>
>       <dependencies>
>         <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
>           <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
>           <version>1.4.2</version>
>           <scope>system</scope>
>           <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
>         </dependency>
>       </dependencies>
>     </profile>
>   </profiles>
>   ...
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Geo, I have modified the maven.xml build in order to add the tools.jar in the classpath.

A pre-goal before java:compile does the stuff:

```
<preGoal name="java:compile">
    <ant:path id="tools">
        <ant:pathelement path="${tools.jar}"/>
    </ant:path>
    <maven:addPath id="maven.dependency.classpath" refid="tools"/>
</preGoal>
```

Comment: `addPath` is provided by `xmlns:maven="jelly:maven"`

Answer (score 3):

```
<classpath>
      <pathelement location="path_to_toold_folder/tools.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Should do the trick.This only works in an ant task.

Comment: I've already done this for a annotations processing classes. But I need to add tools.jar for dependencies (apt too) that are not inside ant tasks.
I need to add tools.jar in the project.xml.